# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setItem')

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to create a simple light/dark mode system with javascript. It works by setting the 'darkTheme' boolean in Window.localStorage
Here is the code I wrote:

```
let lightThemeCheckbox = document.getElementById('lightThemeCheckbox');
let body = document.body;

updateLightTheme();

lightThemeCheckbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    Window.localStorage.setItem('darkTheme', this.checked);
});

function updateLightTheme() {
    let darkTheme = window.localStorage.getItem('darkTheme');

    if(darkTheme == undefined) {
        body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
        return;
    }

    body.style.backgroundColor = darkTheme ? 'rgb(100, 100, 100)' : 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
}
```

But for some reason, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setItem')
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (header.js:7)
(anonymous) @ header.js:7
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: There is no static `localStorage` property. You mean `window.localStorage`. But this is an interesting point: did you get the idea of `Window.localStorage` from the title of the [MDN docs](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)? This would be an amazing argument to finally change it to `Window.prototype.localStorage` via pull request like all of the ECMAScript-native API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put "window" with a capital `w`. You can use the following:

#### Using lowercase `window`

```js
const lightThemeCheckbox = document.getElementById('lightThemeCheckbox');
const body = document.body;

updateLightTheme();

lightThemeCheckbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
    window.localStorage.setItem('darkTheme', this.checked);
});

function updateLightTheme() {
    const darkTheme = window.localStorage.getItem('darkTheme');

    if (darkTheme == undefined) {
        body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
        return;
    }

    body.style.backgroundColor = darkTheme ? 'rgb(100, 100, 100)' : 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
}
```

#### Using `localStorage` without `window`

```js
const lightThemeCheckbox = document.getElementById('lightThemeCheckbox');
const body = document.body;

updateLightTheme();

lightThemeCheckbox.addEventListener('change', () => {
    localStorage.setItem('darkTheme', this.checked);
});

function updateLightTheme() {
    const darkTheme = localStorage.getItem('darkTheme');

    if (darkTheme == undefined) {
        body.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
        return;
    }

    body.style.backgroundColor = darkTheme ? 'rgb(100, 100, 100)' : 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';
}
```

**Hoped this helped!**